# 400 BAD Request error on HttpMethod.PUT - File upload second time

Tags: spring-boot, inputstream, put, multipart, http-method

I have a PUT request method in the controller where I upload zip file and the method takes it as inputstream and processes the stream. It works well with file sizes of Kb. Now I uploaded a zip file of 10Mb size, and it works fine the first time. The second time, it doesn't upload and I get the BAD request error. When I restart the service, it works fine for the first time and the second time I receive the same BAD Request 400 error. Pease advise

```
@RequestMapping(path = “/upload/{fileName}”, method = PUT,
    consumes = "multipart/form-data", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")

 public void upload(@PathVariable(“fileName”) String fileName,
            @RequestBody MultipartFile[] multipartFile) throws IOException{ 

        //inputstream is processed here

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upload a file in spring boot i prefere this approache :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.PUT) // Or POST
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

    System.out.println(String.format("File name %s", file.getName()));
    System.out.println(String.format("File original name %s", file.getOriginalFilename()));
    System.out.println(String.format("File size %s", file.getSize()));

    //do whatever you want with the MultipartFile
    file.getInputStream();
}
```

**Configuring Multipart File Uploads in Spring Boot**

The most used properties are:

1. **spring.http.multipart.file-size-threshold:** A threshold after which the files are written to disk. Supports MB or KB as suffixes to indicate size in Megabyte or Kilobyte
2. **spring.http.multipart.location:** location of the temporary files
3. **spring.http.multipart.max-file-size:** Max size per file the upload supports; also supports the MB or KB suffixes; **by default 1MB**
4. **spring.http.multipart.max-request-size:** max size of the whole request; also supports the MB or KB suffixes

You can of course change these config in your application.properties of yml.

In your case i prefere that you go to your rest api and you check the stack error to see what is the exacte error.

Comment: I get this error "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8' not supported"

Comment: You can use postman to test yout rest endpoint ? if yes you chose binary and you can put your file to upload and tell me what you get